# Subscribe BehaviorSubject to Observable, but ignore errors and termination

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I have a `BehaviorSubject` used by various classes in my application.

Sometimes, I want to publish to it a new data from server. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubject<Entity>(undefined);

loadDataFromServer().subscribe(subject);
```

The `loadDataFromServer()` function returns an `Observable<Entity>`, which emits one `Entity` on subscription and then finishes.

With such implementation, the `BehaviorSubject` will also terminate when the observable terminates. However, I would like to avoid this.

Of course, I can do:

```
loadDataFromServer().subscribe(entity => subject.next(entity));
```

However, I was wondering, are there other options to filter out error and termination events from the source observable? Or is it the optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is fine and probably the easiest way to do it. However, if you want to do this with operators you could use `materialize()` and `dematerialize()`. This will first convert every emission into a special `Notification` object (all notifications will be wrapped and sent as `next`) where you can filter out everything but `next` notifications and then with `dematerialize()` convert them back to real emissions

```
loadDataFromServer()
  .pipe(
    materialize(),
    filter(notification => notification.kind === 'N'),
    dematerialize(),
  )
  .subscribe(subject);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not short, but interesting.

Comment: yeah, I know. I'd personally stay with what you have now :)